# Change structure of object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have some data

```
arr = {
  'a': ['1', '2', '3'],
  'b': ['2', '3', '4'],
  'c': ['3', '5', '6'],
}
```

How can I change this to

```
newArr = {
  '1': ['a'],
  '2': ['a', 'b'],
  '3': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  '4': ['b'],
  '5': ['c'],
  '6': ['c']
}
```

Would the most efficient way to do something like this

```
const newData = {};
Object.keys(oldData).forEach(key => {
  newData[key].forEach(value => {
    if (!newData[value]) {
      newData[value] = [];
    }
    newData[value].push(key);
  });
});
```

Wouldn't it be quite easy with ES6, maybe using `reduce()`?

Comment: If you are amenable to adding a library for this, [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/) has lots of great utility functions for manipulating objects and arrays-- probably optimized under the hood.

Comment: You want `oldData[key].forEach(…)` not `newData[key].forEach(…)`, but apart from that it's fine.

Comment: you need `reduce` instead

Comment: `[ ...new Set(Object.keys(arr).reduce((a,b)=>[...a,...arr[b]],[])) ];`

Answer (score 1):

Just change one line

```
newData[key].forEach(value => {
```

to

```
oldData[key].forEach(value => {
```

```js
var oldData = {
  'a': ['1', '2', '3'],
  'b': ['2', '3', '4'],
  'c': ['3', '5', '6'],
};


const newData = {};
Object.keys(oldData).forEach(key => {
  oldData[key].forEach(value => {
// ^^^^^^ change to oldData instead of newData
    if (!newData[value]) {
      newData[value] = [];
    }
    newData[value].push(key);
  });
});
console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `reduce()` and one `forEach()` like this.

```js
var arr = {
  'a': ['1', '2', '3'],
  'b': ['2', '3', '4'],
  'c': ['3', '5', '6'],
}

var result = Object.keys(arr).reduce(function(r, e) {
  arr[e].forEach(function(a) {
    if (!r[a]) r[a] = [];
    r[a].push(e)
  })
  return r;
}, {});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Why use `reduce` instead of `forEach`?

Comment: Why not, also OP asked for it.

Comment: What a line `r[a] = (r[a] || []).concat(e)` you have changed my code forever

Comment: @NenadVracar Then why wouldn't you replace the inner `forEach` by `reduce` as well?

Comment: @synthet1c It's a bad idea. `concat` creates new arrays.

Comment: @synthet1c …so you shouldn't use it when you strive for efficiency or ease to read.

Comment: @Oriol but it set's the reference to the new copied array so there is no chance of mutation within the inner loop

Comment: @synthet1c You are missing the point. Using `concat` inside a loop will first copy the old array into a new array, and add the current item. If you have `n` iterations, that will cost `1+2+...+n = O(n²)`, while it could easily be linear.